# .NET transaction for Entitity Framework and WebAPI calls

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, transactions

I have the following sequential calls to EF (Entity Framework) and Web API from an MVC controller.

1. Create a Customer using EF `DBContext`.
2. Create an Order for the customer using EF `DBContext`.
3. Charge the customer by calling a Web API which calls the Paypal API.
4. Update the Order to be of successful payment by using EF `DBContext`.
5. Call a Shipping Web API to notify to ship the order. Web API calls an EF `DBContext` to create database entries.

As you may notice, all my calls are not using the same EF DBContext. I would have used the transaction as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) if all were the same database related but I have two WebAPI calls which need to be part of the transaction too.

Is it possible to achieve the same with [Transaction Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Good question. Distributed transactions are hard and brittle. It is best to avoid them. If you are using a distributed microservices approach then you'll have to live with such problems. A big drawback of that approach.